# DOM-Element-specific function overriding or function

Tags: jquery

Say I want to make a little plugin called 'alertMeOnRemove', which is self explanatory. I want it to override the `remove()` function for just the elements it is called on.

```
$('a').alertMeOnRemove();
$('div').remove(); // no alert
$('a.subset-of-a').remove(); //alert
$('a').remove() //alert
```

I know general overriding of jQuery function is both possible and easy. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that wouldn't be difficult.

```
(function(){
    var _remove = $.fn.remove;

    $.fn.alertMeOnRemove = function(){
        this.each(function(){
            $.data(this, 'alertMeOnRemove', true);
        });
    };

    $.fn.remove = function(){
        this.each(function(){
            if ($.data(this, 'alertMeOnRemove')) {
                alert('removing item');
            }
        });

        _remove.call(this);
    };
})();
```

Comment: Excellent! That is exactly what I was looking for. Did not work exactly as you have it, however... `_remove.call(this);` has to be outside the `.each()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I get you, but you can do it like:

```
var _oldRemove = $.fn.remove;
$.fn.remove = function() {
    if(/* some condition */)
       alert('foobar');

    _oldRemove.apply(this, arguments);
};
```